# check if array is chronological

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a list of integer arrays, and i want to check for each array if the array if chronological, if it is not I want it to be removed from the list.

At the moment I do it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allXcombis.Count(); i++)
{
    bool remove = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < allXcombis[i].Length; j++)
    {
        if (allXcombis[i].Count() - 1 > j)
            if (allXcombis[i][j] != allXcombis[i][j + 1] - 1)
                remove = true;
    }
    if (remove)
        allXcombis.Remove(allXcombis[i]);
}
```

but I am not really happy with this code, I think it can be done easier.

Comment: @petar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronological

Answer (score 2):

First, I would probably extract the checking that the array is “chronological” into its own method and made it more efficient, by `return`ing from the loop early:

```
bool IsChronological(int[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] != array[i + 1] - 1)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And then I would simply use [`RemoveAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx):

```
allXcombis.RemoveAll(a => !IsChronological(a));
```

This way, you get concise, readable code and you don't have to worry about indexes in the list (as others mentioned, you have a bug in your code, because you're not careful about the indexes).

Answer (score 0):

When you are removing from list inside loop, you need either to fix loop variable or to loop backwards. Then, you don't need () after Count. And you can break from loop after assigning remove = true, this will improve performance.

```
for (int i = allXcombis.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    bool remove = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < allXcombis[i].Length; j++)
    {
        if (allXcombis[i].Length - 1 > j)
        {
            if (allXcombis[i][j] != allXcombis[i][j + 1] - 1)
            {
                remove = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (remove)
        allXcombis.Remove(allXcombis[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by chronological you mean sorted, then you need to check < not !=.
Also you can simplify some things. The most important is when you find that it's not sorted to break out of the inner loop, so that you don't keep iterating.
Also you need to decrease i when you remove, because you'll skip some arrays otherwise (say if i = 2 and you remove the second array, then the third array becomes second, but i will be 3 on the next iteration, so you'll skip it)

```
for (int i = 0; i < allXcombis.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < allXcombis[i].Length-1; j++)
    {
        if (allXcombis[i][j] > allXcombis[i][j + 1] - 1)
        {
            allXcombis.Remove(allXcombis[i]);
            i--;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for () after Count if it is List

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick) in the use of a dedicated method like he proposed "IsChronological" but I would like to add a little bit of security and performance to this method:

```
bool IsChronological(int[] array)
{
    bool result = ((array == null) || (array.Length == 0)) ? false : true; //Null or empty arrays are not chronological by definition (also avoid exceptions)
    if (result)
    {
        result = (array.Length == 1) ? true : false; //Arrays with only one element are chronological by definition
        if (!result)
        {
            int length = array.Length - 1;
            int index = 0;
            while ((index < length) && (array[index] == array[index] + 1))
                index++;
            result = (index == array.length);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```